# Content script programatically injected by Chrome extension background page got injected multiple times

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension, say it injects content script a.js into urls matching 'http://example.com/*'. Then when I click some page elements in example.com page, a.js would ask background to create a new tab with defined url, and programatically inject a content script b.js into the new tab, you can check the code down:

```
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: 'http://example.com'
}, function (tab) {
    var taskTab = tab.id;
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        if (tabId === taskTab) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(taskTab, {
                file: 'scripts/b.js'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is, the content script b.js would get injected into the new tab for a lot times. I also tried the [`chrome.webNavigation`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation), the result is the same.

So if I want the b.js got injected into the new tab for only one time? how can i make it?

By the way, the b.js is actually a remote file, I load it into page by jQuery, here to simplify the question I make it a local file.

Thanks very much.

### update

I had figure out what's going on with my code.

First, it's wrong for me to wrap the `onUpdated` event listener inside the `create` callback, every time I create a new tab, close it, create it again, the event listener would got bind one more time. The more, the more.

Second, @Xan was right, I could do it by checking `changeInfo.status`. So the code would be:

```
var taskTab;
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: 'http://example.com'
}, function (tab) {
    taskTab = tab.id;
});
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status === 'complete'){
    if (tabId === taskTab) {
       chrome.tabs.executeScript(taskTab, {
            file: 'scripts/b.js'
        });
    }
  }
});
```

And that b.js would only be injected for once, no matter it's a local file or a remote file loaded by jQuery.

Comment: have you tried running it with `b.js` as a local file to reproduce the error?

Comment: @NimaVaziri, yes, it can be reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `onUpdated` event can fire for a lot of reasons:

   > `object changeInfo`:
   >
   > Lists the changes to the state of the tab that was updated.
   >
   > `string (optional) status`: The status of the tab. Can be either loading or complete.
   >
   > `string (optional) url`: The tab's URL if it has changed.
   >
   > `boolean (optional) pinned`: The tab's new pinned state.
   >
   > `string (optional) favIconUrl`: The tab's new favicon URL.

   You might want to filter `onUpdated` events by those properties of `changeInfo`
2. Failsafe method: when you inject a second script, set some guard variable that is checked for `undefined` before you execute the rest of the script. Any other attempts to inject the script will be in the same context and will see the variable set. Kind of like C's `#ifndef` includes.

Comment: 1. I also tried the changeInfo status, no luck with 'loading' or 'complete', it seems like even the status under `onUpdated` event happens many times. 2. I did have some guard ways to prevent the content script be executed for many times, but it still make no sense that the extension injected the content script into new tab for many times. We expect it only once, not many.

Comment: @chenxsan I don't understand, why are you injecting inside `onUpdated` and not inside `create` callback?

Comment: if I inject it inside `create` callback, the code(it appends some html code into the `body` tag) sometime doesn't work. So I have to inject inside `onUpdated`, it's kind of a workaround.

Comment: @chenxsan It's a bad workaround. Consider that you can specify `runAt : 'document_idle'` in `executeScript` to delay injection until it's ready. If that's not helping either, consider wrapping your injected code in a listener for a particular DOM event after which it's safe to inject.

Comment: The default value for `runAt` in `executeScript` is [`document_idle`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-InjectDetails), I had try all the other values like `document_end` etc. No luck too. It's really annoying but I guess I would have a try.